# How to measure interval time from two individual time with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, time, intervals

I have some column fields respectively pid(primary key), login, logout, interval_time, today(current_date)

login and logout data types are (time without time zone)

Here login and logout data data such like 10:00:45, 12:45:12, 07: 32:02( not like 14:32:12, 18:65:78, 23:51:00)

So i can't understand when night or day, or pm or am.

```
If someone login = 07:00:00 and logout = 11:00:00
again he/she login = 01:00:00
that means here interval_time will be 2 hours. Exactly how much time he/she was inactive.
```

## I've written a trigger

```
create or replace function interval_time()
returns trigger as
$BODY$
    begin
        if new.login or new.logout then
            if new.login then
                update employee set interval_time = new.logout::time - login::time where pid = new.pid; -- employee is my table name;
                return new;
            end if;
        end if;
    end;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

## this trigger just sample, it doesn't work.

```
create trigger employee_changer
before update
on employee
for each row
execute procedure employee_change()

Please let me know if you have any question.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.
```

Comment: Don't use `update` in the trigger function, simply assign the value: `new.interval_time := new.logout - new.login;` - but there is no need to store that information as it can easily (and cheaply) be derived from the existing data.

Comment: but i'm getting interval_time = 10:00:00.  if 10:00:00 - 01:00:00 here exact result will be 03:00:00. This is the main problem here.